# Cast ContentItem to the strongly type

Tags: .net, lucene.net, kentico-kontent

I'm building a site using [Kentico Cloud](https://kenticocloud.com/) with [.Net SDK](https://github.com/Kentico/delivery-sdk-net) providing search functionality using the [Lucene.Net](https://lucenenet.apache.org/) to store index items.

I would like to create [strongly typed model](https://github.com/Kentico/delivery-sdk-net/wiki/Working-with-strongly-typed-models) from [DeliveryClient.ContentItem](https://github.com/Kentico/delivery-sdk-net#contentitem-structure) in the search implementation.

I have implemented the like that:

```cs
var result = await client.GetItemAsync("home");
var item = result.Item; // ContentItem
// ToObject is my own implementation that does the conversion
return item?.ToObject(CustomTypeProvider.GetType(item?.system?.type));
```

I would much rather use a **built-in** method to get the strongly typed model than having to use a switch that needs to be updated whenever I add new content types (To The ToObject method).

> This question is a migrated from official Kentico Cloud Forum, that would be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ContentItem.CastTo<object>()` method (or `DeliveryItemResponse.CastTo<object>()` / `DeliveryItemListingResponse.CastTo<object>()`) method with `object` as a generics.

Example with `ContentItem.CastTo()` method

```cs
var result = await client.GetItemAsync("home");
var item = result.Item; // ContentItem
return item?.CastTo<object>() // Automatically converts to the desired strongly content type
```

Example with `ContentItemResponse.CastTo` method
[image: ContentItemResponse example]